# Why is there 8GB worth of files in my /tmp?

Tags: disk-usage, tmp

I just got a notification saying I have a small amount of disk space left:

[image: low disk space]

so I opened baobab to investigate and noticed this:

[image: baobab]

It turns out that my /tmp folder is full of files names like `tmpxxxxxx`. These look to me like temporary files created by a python script.

How can I find out what program is causing this?

The timestamps vary between approximately when I first logged in to now.
They are binary files and file managers see them as type 'unknown'.

`lsof /tmp/tmp*` gives nothing.

When I run  `ls -l /tmp/tmp*`, the last 10 entries are:

```
-rw------- 1 david  david  21195909 2011-08-29 21:53 /tmp/tmpzTXYNT
-rw------- 1 david  david      2381 2011-08-29 15:53 /tmp/tmpZuKqAW
-rw------- 1 david  david   6987663 2011-08-29 18:38 /tmp/tmpZuSEp5
-rw------- 1 david  david   1789626 2011-08-29 20:33 /tmp/tmpzv3MST
-rw------- 1 david  david  19266899 2011-08-29 22:15 /tmp/tmpZxMCU5
-rw------- 1 david  david  21197879 2011-08-29 20:52 /tmp/tmpzxSXv2
-rw------- 1 david  david     65960 2011-08-29 18:13 /tmp/tmpZyA6aJ
-rw------- 1 david  david    352529 2011-08-29 22:47 /tmp/tmpzz3jPd
-rw------- 1 david  david     13869 2011-08-29 22:25 /tmp/tmp_ZZ3ZA
-rw------- 1 david  david  17277993 2011-08-29 20:53 /tmp/tmpZzSmnL
```

Comment: Can you list a few of them `ls -l /tmp/tmp*`?

Comment: Try `strings /tmp/tmpXXX` or `hexdump -C /tmp/tmpXXX`, then post the interesting bits.

Comment: Use `file /tmp/tmp*` to get the file types.

Comment: The file command tells me 'data'.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `inotify-tools` package?

You can install it and try the following:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ lsof `inotifywait -e create --format "/tmp/%f" .`
```

If you create a file in another terminal, like:

```
$ cat > /tmp/aa
```

the `lsof` output might show something like

```
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
cat     3576 marcelo    1w   REG    8,1        0 274376 /tmp/aa
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the lsof command again and I got this:

```
COMMAND     PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
ubuntuone 21086 david   49r   REG    8,4  1790938 1473680 /tmp/tmpYemldG
ubuntuone 21086 david   50r   REG    8,4    12903 1473668 /tmp/tmpzZZV7s
ubuntuone 21086 david   52r   REG    8,4    21702 1473689 /tmp/tmpXrw6n8
ubuntuone 21086 david   53r   REG    8,4    25645 1473683 /tmp/tmp5jFc1h
ubuntuone 21086 david   54r   REG    8,4   275049 1473685 /tmp/tmphrw2g3
ubuntuone 21086 david   55r   REG    8,4   501273 1473684 /tmp/tmpbu2ET8
ubuntuone 21086 david   56r   REG    8,4  7027579 1473687 /tmp/tmpSY_QO8
ubuntuone 21086 david   57r   REG    8,4 19404032 1473686 /tmp/tmpokUSil
ubuntuone 21086 david   58r   REG    8,4 17277993 1473688 /tmp/tmpqjYsMG
ubuntuone 21086 david   59r   REG    8,4 21198443 1473682 /tmp/tmp1QGY_A
```

So it looks like Ubuntu One is the culprit. For some reason it doesn't seem to clean up after itself. I 'solved' this by killing ubuntuone-syncdaemon and then running `sudo rm -f /tmp/tmp*`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu One has a design flaw
It replicates data files in /tmp. I'm talking GB of data just filling up /tmp
I disabled and voila, got my disk space back (after reboot)

The basic flaw of Ubuntu One is not implementing a repository based lock on a file while updating it and doing out of place synchronization
All the rest is Ubuntu One developers excuses for a poor design.

My advice - disable it .

Once a week  / when you add new data enable, allow to update andthen disable it again and restart.

Terrible way, but the only way you don't lose your disk space